# Is there a way to define test functions inside of the class that is being tested?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to define test functions inside of the class that is being tested?

I come from a C/C++/D background, so I'm used to being able to use conditional compilation to make parts of the code compile for unittests but not for a release build. However, in kotlin or java I'm given to understand that the only way to effect a similar result is to write a separate file that is only compiled for the unittests' target. I really don't want to make my code less legible by splitting it unnecessarily into two files and I really don't want to compile in functions that shouldn't appear in the release build, so how can I avoid that?

People always look at me strangely when I talk about how nice it is to have at least some of the unittests inline with the code they are testing, so here's a rough example of how I can do this in C++ using any typical unittesting framework like CUnit.

```
class Foo
{
   ...
}

#ifdef BUILD_UNITTESTS
void test_MyTestCase()
{
   ...
}

MY_MACRO_TO_REGISTER_TESTCASE_WITH_TESTING_FRAMEWORK(test_MyTestCase)
#endif
```

How would one do something equivalent in Kotlin or Java?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want but JVM languages just don't do that (either encouraging embedded tests or capable of `#ifdef` alternative compilations). A common convention (picked up from build tools like Maven or Gradle) is to have mirrored package/directory structures:

- `src/main/java/x/y/z/Foo.java`
- `src/test/java/x/y/z/FooTest.java`

IDEs know such conventions and can jump between the two quite easily (Ctrl-Shift-T on IntelliJ).